# How can I enable flat surface reflections in UE4 on mobile?

Tags: mobile, unreal-4, reflection-rendering

Could someone please tell me how do I enable reflections on flat surfaces on a mobile in UE4? I have a simple room with one directional light. I need reflections on the tables and ground planes. I have tried every single setting and variation possible and nothing works.

I have tested the Sun Temple demo project and the Reflection Content Example demo project and nether of those projects have reflections on the mobile (iPhone 6). Those projects do have some kind of glare on the ground plans but noting close to what would be classified as a realistic reflection.

SSR does not work on mobile, neither do Sphere or Box Reflection captures. An alternative solution to get reflections working may be to use a Scene Capture Cube, but they don't work on mobile either.

UE4 is suppose to be an amazing game engine but it doesn't even offer the ability to support reflections on mobile. Reflections are quite simple to get running in Unity.

I have spent so much time trying to get reflections to work, and the worst thing is, every post or document that i have read about this subject does not offer a solution.

If someone could please confirm for me that reflections do not work on mobile or offer me a solution to get detailed reflections displaying on the ground and tables I would be so appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

UE4 does not support real-time reflections because of its render strategy.

You can have pre-computer reflection with special reflection-caption spheres, but I guess they are turned off for mobile due to a) size constraints of the resulting files and b) performance constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any idea how to turn them on?

Comment: I don't think you can turn it on. Maybe you can try to run the reflection content examples on a mobile device to see if any of it works there: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/ContentExamples/Reflections/index.html

EPIC has to strip a lot of stuff from the engine to make it slim enough for mobile devices, so I guess they threw reflections out completely. If you REALLY need reflection you have to fake it with materials and material parameters.